# Convert schedule in pdf to calendar file

Tags: excel, pdf, icalendar

I have a pdf that contains the match schedule of all teams in our competitions.
How can I get the schedule of 1 team in a calendar file?

This is the pdf: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=10142707428734526357

I'm guessing I have to convert the pdf to excel? And then filter that excel file and format it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use https://www.pdftoexcelonline.com/en/ to convert your pdf to excel. You will end up with 34 sheets.
2. combine all sheets into one - LOTS of questions on SO with advice on combining sheets.
   You could use a macro ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361488/how-do-i-copy-same-columns-which-are-laterally-placed-from-different-worksheets?rq=1)), or you could simply create a new sheet, and either copy-paste, or use links like: 
   `A1='page 1'!A1`
   `B1='page 1'!B1`
   ...
   `A35='page 2'!A1`
   ...
   `A70='page 3'!A1`
3. Format your csv file using directions [here](http://n8henrie.com/2013/05/spreadsheet-to-calendar/) (part 2: "Formatting the spreadsheet")
4. you can import a csv file into google calendar. [Here is a walk through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7tubuLVSNU)